# Different result when trying looping for the output

Tags: arrays, delphi, output

Here is my code, lets assumption that i have got this

```
a[i,j];
```

Then i count this

```
//count b
for i := 0 to 4 do 
begin
  for j := 0 to 5 do 
  begin
    b[0,j] := nilEn * a[i,j];
    b[1,j] := nilPro * a[i,j];
    b[2,j] := nilKar * a[i,j];
    b[3,j] := nilLem * a[i,j];
    b[4,j] := nilVit * a[i,j];
    Memo1.Lines.Append(FloatToStr(b[i,j]));
  end;
end;
```

Here is the problem, when i compare the result from memo1 and memo2, it gives different result

```
for i := 0 to 4 do
begin
  for j := 0 to 5 do
  begin
    Memo2.Lines.Append(FloatToStr(b[i,j]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What is `a[]` declared as, and what is it filled with?  What is `b[]` declared as?  What is being output to `Memo1`?  To `Memo2`?  You need to provide more details about the expected output and problem with the actual output.

Comment: Why do you assign b[0,j] five times?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : a[] and b[] is matrix 2 dimensions with 5 rows and 4 columns. Values in a[] will be used for calculating b[]. Memo1 and Memo2 is output for b[] values. Such as b[0,0] = 3 b[0,1] = 4

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I assump that nilEn, nilPro, etc is different. But As Jens Borrisholt said. It can be done by change it in to array (nice).
But I wanna asking, is it possible to make it as dynamic(variables)? not as constanta.

Comment: But why do you assign 5 times to the same variable? Only the last one has any impact. If you understand that it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you do i diffrent.

```
for i := 0 to 4 do 
  for j := 0 to 5 do 
  begin
    b[0,j] := nilEn * a[i,j];
    b[1,j] := nilPro * a[i,j];
    b[2,j] := nilKar * a[i,j];
    b[3,j] := nilLem * a[i,j];
    b[4,j] := nilVit * a[i,j];
    Memo1.Lines.Append(FloatToStr(b[i,j]));
  end;
```

should have been:

```
const 
   Values : array[0..4] of integer = (nilEn, nilPro, nilKar, nilLem, nilVit);

for i := 0 to 4 do 
begin
  for j := 0 to 5 do 
  begin
    b[i,j] := Values[i] * a[i,j];
    Memo1.Lines.Append(FloatToStr(b[i,j]));
  end;
end;
```

An other solution with valued as a variable:

```
var
   Values : array[0..4] of integer;
   Values[0] := nilEn;
   Values[1] := nilPro; 
   Values[2] := nilKar; 
   Values[3] := nilLem; 
   Values[4] := nilVit;


for i := 0 to 4 do 
begin
  for j := 0 to 5 do 
  begin
    b[i,j] := Values[i] * a[i,j];
    Memo1.Lines.Append(FloatToStr(b[i,j]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is it possible to make 'Values' as variables? not as constanta.
I get nilEn, nilPro, nilKar, etc. from edittext.

Comment: Of course that's possible. Declare an array of length 5, populate it and pass it in.